# Delphi EOutOfResources Screen Capturing

Tags: multithreading, image, delphi, network-programming

The program which is giving this error. Sometimes immediately, sometimes after a short time

http://www1.datafilehost.com/d/39f524c0  Thread Suspends in some try finally block

Source:

http://www1.datafilehost.com/d/1cae7b24 EOufOfResources During debugging

Im sorry for bad English. I have the following problem: I try to do 5 fps screenshots and draw the cursor icon on them, recode BMP in PNG and send it over the network through blocking sockets Indy. After sending a screenshot proportionally compressed and placed on TImage (desktopimage) on the main form. If I'm doing all this in a timer - that everything works fine if I am doing all of this code in Synchronize() it also works fine, but it causes freezing of the interface, I want to get rid of it, and doing so in PNG compression in the thread, now I tried to break several Synchronize() to find the error (I get an error EOutOfResources), but I could not. Please help. Here is my code:

```
  TCaptureThread = class(TThread)
  private
   bmp: TBitmap;
   DC: HDC;
   h:hwnd;
   thumbRect : TRect;
   maxWidth, maxHeight:integer;
   png:TPNGImage;
   Stream:TMemoryStream;
   RecBlock:TCommBlock;
   r: TRect;
   CI: TCursorInfo;
   Icon: TIcon;
   II: TIconInfo;
   commblock:TCommblock;
   procedure showthumb;
   procedure send;
   procedure stretch;
   procedure getscreen;
   procedure fixsize;
  protected
   procedure Execute; override;
   constructor Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean);
   destructor destroy; override;
end;

 constructor TCaptureThread.Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean);
 begin
  bmp:=TBitmap.Create;
  Stream:=TMemoryStream.Create;
  png:=TPNGImage.Create;
  Icon := TIcon.Create;
  inherited Create(CreateSuspended);
 end;


 destructor TCaptureThread.destroy;
 begin
  png.Free;
  bmp.Free;
  Icon.Free;
  stream.Free;
  inherited;
 end;

 procedure TCaptureThread.Execute;
 begin
  inherited;
  while not Terminated do
  begin
   Synchronize(fixsize);
   Synchronize(getscreen);
   r := bmp.Canvas.ClipRect;
  try
   CI.cbSize := SizeOf(CI);
   if GetCursorInfo(CI) then
   if CI.Flags = CURSOR_SHOWING then
   begin
    Icon.Handle := CopyIcon(CI.hCursor);
    if GetIconInfo(Icon.Handle, II) then
    begin
      bmp.Canvas.Draw(
            ci.ptScreenPos.x - Integer(II.xHotspot) - r.Left - Form4.Left,
            ci.ptScreenPos.y - Integer(II.yHotspot) - r.Top - Form4.Top,
            Icon
            );
    end;
   end;
  finally

  end;
  try
   png.Assign(bmp);
   png.CompressionLevel := 9;
   png.SaveToStream(stream);
   stream.Position :=0;
   Recblock.Command :='STREAM';
   Recblock.Msg :='';
   Recblock.NameFrom := MyName;
   Synchronize(send);
  finally

  end;
  try
   thumbRect.Left := 0;
   thumbRect.Top := 0;
   if bmp.Width > bmp.Height then
   begin
    thumbRect.Right := maxWidth;
    thumbRect.Bottom := (maxWidth * bmp.Height) div bmp.Width;
   end
   else
   begin
    thumbRect.Bottom := maxHeight;
    thumbRect.Right := (maxHeight * bmp.Width) div bmp.Height;
   end;
   Synchronize(stretch);
   bmp.Width := thumbRect.Right;
   bmp.Height := thumbRect.Bottom;
   Synchronize(showthumb);
  finally
  end;

  sleep(200);
  end;

  end;

  procedure TCaptureThread.getscreen;
  begin
   DC:=GetDC(0);
   bitblt(bmp.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, Form4.Width+Form4.Left, Form4.Height+Form4.Top,         
   DC, Form4.Left, Form4.Top, SRCCOPY);
   ReleaseDC(0, DC);
  end;

  procedure TCaptureThread.fixsize;
  begin
   maxWidth := Form1.DesktopImage.Width;
   maxHeight := Form1.DesktopImage.Height;
   bmp.Height:=Form4.Height;
   bmp.Width:=Form4.Width;
  end;

  procedure TCaptureThread.send;
  begin
   Form1.Streamclient.IOHandler.Write(RawToBytes(Recblock,sizeof(recblock)),sizeof(recblock));
   Form1.Streamclient.IOHandler.Write(stream,stream.Size,true);
  end;

  procedure TCaptureThread.showthumb;
  begin
   Form1.DesktopImage.Picture.Assign(bmp);
  end;

  procedure TCaptureThread.stretch;
  begin
   SetStretchBltMode(bmp.Canvas.Handle, HALFTONE);  
   StretchBlt(bmp.Canvas.Handle,0,0,thumbRect.Right,thumbRect.Bottom,bmp.Canvas.Handle,0,0,bmp.Width,bmp.Height,SRCCOPY);
  end;
```

Comment: I cannot understand the question.

Comment: I get an error EOutOfResources and cant fix it

Comment: My understanding is not improved by that comment. I can't tell what you are trying to achieve. If you posted a program that produced the fault, we could run it. I suggest you edit your question to do just that.

Comment: It is a client server program and interacts with MS SQL Server 2008, even if I'll post it will be required to preset. The work of this part of the code is only possible when connecting to the server, now I'm not ready to separate the code and write the individual client - server, which can be easily run, it will take too much time.

Comment: If it's too much effort for you, it's too much effort for me. Pay us some respect. Do the work needed to help us to help you.

Comment: You're right, I understand perfectly, I meant at this moment I do not have time to bring the code into a separate program. I'll write it tomorrow

Comment: I posted it, but this program works with out network

Comment: Just as sidenote TCanvas is not threadsave I wrote a microprogramm to demonstrate, source can bet get from  http://www.bummisoft.de/download/Demo_Thread_CanvasProblem.zip

Comment: Thank you for putting in the effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem. Wrote the code in   `Synchronize()`, except PNG compression and before compression used method `Canvas.Lock`, after compression `Canvas.UnLock`. This allows you to avoid the influence of the another thread to `Canvas`. Thanks for  bummi's advice(TCanvas is not threadsave). Correctly `Execute` method is here:

```
procedure TCaptureThread.Execute;
begin
inherited;
 while not Terminated do
 begin
 Synchronize(size);
 Synchronize(getscreen);
 Synchronize(drawcursor);

 try
 png.Canvas.Lock;
 bmp.Canvas.Lock;
 png.Assign(bmp);
 png.CompressionLevel := 9;
 png.Canvas.Unlock;
 bmp.Canvas.Unlock;
 finally

 end;
 try
 Synchronize(stretch);
 Synchronize(showthumb);
 finally

 end;

 sleep(200);
 end;

end;
```

Answer (score 2):

First in my delphi 2010 i must replace

```
unit CaptureUnit;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs;
```

with

```
unit CaptureUnit;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants,
  Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs;
```

The same also in unit.pas

You should not assign a Bitmap to `Picture.Assign(bmp);`

```
procedure TCaptureThread.showthumb;
begin
    CaptureForm.DesktopImage.Picture.Assign(bmp);
end;
```

After a short time I get also an error EOutOfResources).

You should assign a Bitmap to  `Picture.Bitmap.Assign(bmp);`

```
procedure TCaptureThread.showthumb;
begin
    CaptureForm.DesktopImage.Picture.Bitmap.Assign(bmp);
end;
```

after I changed it, I got your program run for 20 minutes without getting an error. Then I finished it manually.

Update:

Screenshot : program running while Vcl Video playing and stretching and moving the Capture Area.

[image]

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you for putting in the effort, but it isnt work. If u dont touch and dont move main form and capture area form, then it works with out ur changes, but if u will do something with visual components then we get this error again (with out and with ur changes). It may be necessary to use methods Canvas.Lock/UnLock, but I dont know how to do it correctly.

Comment: @Sibay : Did you test it with `your test program` ? As I write this now, it already runs 40 minutes. I Did the capture area enlarged, reduced, launched 20 different applications. Drawn across the window. In VLC Media PLayer a video started to run over the Capture Area. what am I supposed to do yet, it runs !

Comment: Maybe it depens by OS version. I use Win7 x64 and it isnt works. I posted correctly code. Thank you for your participation.

Comment: @Sibay : Do you want the program compiled with Delphi 2010 on xp, test for yourself? If interested, it could provide it for download.

Comment: I think this is due to the fact that the 32 bit OS version handles more messeges than 64 bit. Maybe I'm wrong. Of course, if you send a link to the program and source code - I'll definitely take a look.